# how to disable JQZOOM on mobile device

Tags: prestashop-1.6, jqzoom

Can Someone please tell me how to disable jqzoom on mobile device because it doesn't work

I'm using prestashop 1.6
thanks

Answer (score -2):

a couple of months later with the answer but maybe this will help someone, (I am using Prestashop 1.6.1.9) locate the file `product.js` (In my example is located on **C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\default-bootstrap\js\product.js**), about **line 153** find **jqzoom**, add the following:

```
compensante = scrollCompensate();
if (($(window).width()+scrollCompensate()) >= 768) {
.
.
.}
```

**For example:**

```
compensante = scrollCompensate();
if (($(window).width()+scrollCompensate()) >= 768) {
    //set jqZoom parameters if needed
    if (typeof(jqZoomEnabled) !== 'undefined' && jqZoomEnabled)
    {
        if ($('#thumbs_list .shown img').length)
        {
            var new_src = $('#thumbs_list .shown img').attr('src').replace('cart_', 'large_');
            if ($('.jqzoom img').attr('src')!= new_src)
                $('.jqzoom img').attr('src', new_src).parent().attr('href', new_src);
        }
        $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
            zoomType: 'innerzoom', // Default : standard - The others admitted option values are 'reverse','drag','innerzoom'
            xzoom: 400, //zooming div default width(default width value is 200)
            yzoom: 400, //zooming div default width(default height value is 200)
            offset: 21 //zooming div default offset(default offset value is 10)         
            title: false
        });
    }
}
```

**Note:** the method `scrollCompensate()` is located on file `global.js`

**"C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\default-bootstrap\js\global.js"**